# What is caddar in scheme

Tags: scheme

I am trying to understand what caddar is in scheme. My notes say that it is a nested version of car or cdr, but it does not explain what combination it is. Here is a code and its output:

```
=>caddar '((a b c) '(d e f)))
;Value: c
```

Can somebody please explain why the output is c here?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's `(car (cdr (cdr (car '((a b c) '(d e f)))`.

You can tell from the name: the order  of `a`s and `d`s tells you which it is. For every `a` you put a `car` and for ever `d` a `cdr`.

Answer (score 3):

car yields the first element. cdr yields the rest. If you wanted to get the first element of the rest of your list, you would use

```
(car (cdr '((a b c) (d e f)))) ;; value: '(d e f)
```

A shorthand for that is to mush the car and cdr together, like so:

```
(cadr '((a b c) (d e f))) ;; value: '(d e f)
```

Note that the 'a' and 'd' in cadr are in the same order as in the original (car (cdr ...))

So caddar is shorthand for:

```
(car (cdr (cdr (car '((a b c) (d e f)))))) ;; value: c
(caddar '((a b c) (d e f))) ;; same as above, but with less typing.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can compose car and cdr.
Think of it as ignoring the 'c' and 'r' then applying car/cdr from right to left.
[example](http://www.dotnetperls.com/cons-car-cdr-cadr-scheme):

```
car  = first item
cdr  = second and all subsequent items in list
cadr = second item
```